# How to generate pdf report from python code plot and result dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, weasyprint

Given a `Pandas.DataFrame` with numeric data, I'm looking for way to output the following directly into a `pdf` file:

- The `Pandas.DataFrame` itself as a table
- The plot of the `Pandas.DataFrame`
- A few lines of text
- A title
- Add a logo on left top side of a page

All these should happen automatically at the end of the sctipt execution.

The `Pandas.DataFrame` is the following:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})

plt.plot(df_out['B'].values)


write text1:
this plot is good 

write text 2:  This table is write
```

Thanks in advance for any sugestions.

Comment: what do you mean by "we lines of code"?

Comment: @MichaelSidorov we is typing mistake, its mean need to add some description text lines at end of pdf page ,(these description lines will about plot and df that we save in pdf page)